# Hibernate: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set

Tags: oracle, hibernate, annotations

I am trying to use Set in hibernate. The problem I don't know to how to write annotation on the Set table.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="user_settings")
    public class UserSettings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private int userid;
    protected Set<Integer>foreignLanguageId;
    public UserSettings() {   

    }
    public UserSettings(int userid, int nativeLanguageId,
            Set<Integer> foreignLanguageId, Date birthday) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.nativeLanguageId = nativeLanguageId;
        this.foreignLanguageId = foreignLanguageId;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="userid", nullable=false)// This annotation
    public Set<Integer> getForeignLanguageId() {
        return foreignLanguageId;
    }
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user_settings, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(foreignLanguageId)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314)...........
```

Comment: I think you should change `protected` to `private` for your `foreignLanguageId` variable and use getters and setters along with it, so it can be mapped in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use entity to make an association not `id`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_settings")
public class UserSettings {

    private Set<Language> foreignLanguages;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_user_setting", nullable = false)
    public Set<Language> getForeignLanguages() {
        return foreignLanguages;
    }

}
```

if you want to use `Integer` you can use `@ElementCollection`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_settings")
public class UserSettings {

    private Set<Integer> foreignLanguages;

    @ElementCollection
    public Set<Integer> getForeignLanguages() {
        return foreignLanguages;
    }

}
```

Comment: I  put:  @ElementCollection, but it is still not working, I am using hibernate 4. I will try to create class Language now. Thx.

Comment: @LayLeangsros It should work even with Hibernate 3. Please, add to the question your code with `@ElementCollection` and a stack trace.